# SQLite Java error when executing complex query with sub-select and window functions

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a (complex) query which uses a sub-select and window functions (which SQLite does support: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/). When running this query in a database tool (dbeaver in this case) this query executes correctly, when running in Java, I get a SQLite error: 
`[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)`

Both use the same jar: `sqlite-jdbc-3.27.2.1.jar`. I've tried trimming the sql string in Java, removing all not-needed spaces. This did not help.

Query:

```sql
SELECT *,
       (SELECT story.name FROM story WHERE story.id = story_id) AS story_name,
       round((STRFTIME('%s', last_reg) - STRFTIME('%s', first_reg)) / (60.0), 2) AS minutes,
       round((STRFTIME('%s', last_reg) - STRFTIME('%s', first_reg)) / (60.0 * 60.0), 2) AS hours
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY story_id, reg_date
             ORDER BY reg_time DESC
           ) reg_number,
           FIRST_VALUE(reg_time) OVER (
             PARTITION BY story_id, reg_date
             ORDER BY reg_time
           ) first_reg,
           LAST_VALUE(reg_time) OVER (
             PARTITION BY story_id,reg_date
             ORDER BY reg_time 
           ) last_reg
      FROM work_registration
     ORDER BY reg_date, reg_time
  );
```

DDL for completeness:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS story
(   id          integer PRIMARY KEY
    name        text    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS work_registration
(   reg_date    text    NOT NULL,
    reg_time    text    NOT NULL,
    description text,            
    story_id    integer NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (story_id) REFERENCES story (id)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_work_registration_date_time_story
ON work_registration (reg_date, reg_time, story_id);
```

Significant piece of Java:

```java
public class HoursDatabaseService {

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:sqlite:mf-plugin-hours.db";

    private Connection connect() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void selectAll() {
        String sql = " ... "; // <- here goes the query

        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
             Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {

            // loop through the result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                 // stuff
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HoursDatabaseService service = new HoursDatabaseService();
        service.selectAll();
    }

}
```

As the database tool runs this correctly, why does the Java results in:
`[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)`?

Obscure thing I noted along the way: if I create a view with this query, the Java fails to start as it finds the view malformed: `[SQLITE_CORRUPT]  The database disk image is malformed (malformed database schema (vw_story_registrations) - near "(": syntax error)`. Funny enough, querying the view in the database tool just works fine...

Why does it not work in Java?

Comment: Are you sure your java program is using the version of sqlite you think it is? Those errors sound like it's using one too old to support window functions.

Comment: try escaping all the single quotes in your SQL string

Comment: @funkyjelly Good tip. Tried it (converted all `'` to `\'` but it did not help unfortunately

Comment: @Shawn "Yeah of course as the database tool points to the jar in the Java project" I was thinking. Double checking... Appears that the IntelliJ Plugin SDK (this piece is part of an IntelliJ plugin) has it own `sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.1.jar`! Thank you!